# How to bring rounded integer as output by multiplying two columns in SQL

Tags: sql

I have two columns A and B in SQL. Column A has value 5.2 and Column B has value 2.1. I am multiplying column A and B in Column C. Answer is 10.92. I would like to get rounded number 11 as Integer in column C instead of 10.92 as float or decimal. How should I write query. Should there be a Cast function or similar?

Sample query is:

```
SELECT *, A multiply B As C
FROM Table X
```

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language used by all relational databases, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: There is a round function. Please check that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need query like this:

```
select *, cast(round((a*b), 0) as int) from X
```

Here you can see on [DB FIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=0bdf8a989d52f23887885b4bd9d60a2a)

Comment: Thanks Marko. How should I give this column a name e.g. C

Comment: Hmm, maybe `RESULT`. And of course, accept my answer if it solves your problem :)

Answer (score 0):

select round((columnA*columnB),0)
from Table